# SQL Query For Product Sales Report

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a query that gives a product sales report by whatever date range I specify.

Something like select whatever from wherever where date ordered between start date and end date order by product id.

My page then loop through the recordset and displays the results on the page in a list.

What I would like to do is provide a list showing PRODUCT A total sales = whatever, PRODUCT B total sales = whatever so on and so forth. So as the loop runs product a = product a + 1

I do this already with staff sales, but there are only 5 staff so I have managed to do this, but there are over 300 product codes.

What is the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Do this in your application code by keeping track of the product code and running totals.  When the product code changes, emit an extra row with the totals into the output.
2. Do something similar to #1, but use a separate GROUP BY query to get the totals.
3. Create a SELECT statement that UNIONs together two queries, one for the product detail lines and one with the summary information.
4. Use some product specific command (you don't say what database you're using) to accomplish #3 without having to do the UNION yourself.  Both MySQL and SQL Server offer (different) ROLL UP clauses that can do what you want.

Comment: Sorry Larry, SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Then look up WITH ROLL UP.  It will do what you want with only minor modifications to your SQL and ASP.

Comment: Thank Larry, that's just the point in the right direction that I needed. Greatly appreciated.